# How to perform a successful login with 'requests' in Python (GET/POST) - 409 Conflict

Tags: python, pyqt, python-requests, python-multithreading

### What is the right way to login through this website?

I want to login [here](https://studentsweb.teimes.gr/unistudent/login.asp?lang=en-us) using the `requests` module.

I've done this so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import requests
from utils.user_agents import get_random_user_agent


class StudentsWebSession(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, url, _url=None, username=None, password=None, payload=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.ua = get_random_user_agent('desktop')
        self.headers_get_one = {
            'host': 'studentsweb.teimes.gr',
            'user-agent': self.ua,
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'connection': 'keep-alive',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1'
        }
        self.headers_post_one = {
            'host': 'studentsweb.teimes.gr',
            'user-agent': self.ua,
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'referer': 'https://studentsweb.teimes.gr/unistudent/login.asp',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'connection': 'keep-alive',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1'
        }
        self.headers_get_two = {
            'host': 'studentsweb.teimes.gr',
            'user-agent': self.ua,
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'referer': 'https://studentsweb.teimes.gr/unistudent/login.asp',
            'connection': 'keep-alive',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1'
        }
        self.url = url
        self._url = _url
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.payload = payload

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def get(self):
        with self.session as s:
            if not self.payload:
                self.payload = {
                    'userName': self.username,
                    'pwd': self.password,
                    'submit1': 'Login',
                    'loginTrue': 'login'
                }

            r = s.get(self.url, headers=self.headers_get_one,
                      params={'lang': 'en-us'})
            print(r.content.decode('cp1253'))
            #print(r.url)

            r = s.post(self.url, headers=self.headers_post_one,
                       data=self.payload)
            #print(r.content.decode('cp1253'))
            #print(r.url)

            #r = s.get(self._url, headers=self.headers_get_two)
            #print(r.content.decode('cp1253'))
            #print(r.url)

    def run(self):
        self.get()
```

I initialize it like this:

```
stweb = StudentsWebSession(db.get('studentsweb', {}).get('url'),
                           db.get('studentsweb', {}).get('url_after'),
                           self.extract_username_from_email(),
                           self.form_password.text())
stweb.start()
```

Where `db` is a dictionary that contains all the needed information.

- `db.get('studentsweb', {}).get('url')`

  - **https://studentsweb.teimes.gr/unistudent/login.asp**
- `db.get('studentsweb', {}).get('url_after')`

  - **https://studentsweb.teimes.gr/unistudent/studentMain.asp**

And as a result, i receive an HTML document with the below title (409 http code)

```
 <title>409 Conflict</title>
```

I think that you must perform a simple GET request to store the cookies, and then perform the POST request with all the required payload, headers and cookies. And then, perform a GET request to receive the desired result.

Here is an demonstration of the above requests:

[image: First Part]

[image: Second Part]

I prefer not using selenium, headless browsers as well as non-threadsafe libraries

If you need more info please do not hesitate to ask for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you initialising `StudentsWebSession` and calling `.get()`? Assuming `self.payload` is `None` and it uses the `self.payload` as defined in the `if` of `.get`, then:

1. `'submit1'` should be `'Είσοδος'`, not `'%C5%DF%F3%EF%E4%EF%F2'`. But since the '%C5...' is already form-encoded and you want to send that with the form data, to prevent requests.post from form-encoding it again, send the [payload as a string](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

   > There are times that you may want to send data that is not form-encoded. If you pass in a string instead of a dict, that data will be posted directly.
   >
   > For example, the GitHub API v3 accepts JSON-Encoded POST/PATCH data:

   ```
   >>> import json

   >>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
   >>> payload = {'some': 'data'}

   >>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
   ```
2. Don't specify 'content-length' in `headers_post_one`.
3. When you do `with requests.Session() as s:`, the session is lost once the login is done. Put it as `with ... as self.session:` and use `self.session` in future requests.
4. A random cookies appears to be getting set when the POST is done. It's being generated by the js on the form submit. You'll need to look at it and re-create the cookie and send that with the post request. Also, it's not the `rcva_` cookie you're getting in the form GET. Only the first 64 chars match up:

   > Set-Cookie:rcva%5F=**FCDB7353DAFB81C0DBDF61BD76CBBB0B4B6D6E39BC7381BEDB8A79416CBE4E9E**16B9A45ABBE6175E103D0CCBBB848AF2C4000C03DDB27444CAFFBFAA7D6D6731A538DC737CE33D5A2B443E4CEF01911D08512B74B2C7062854F0857937DB92793E1FAE8518917CAD3EC03997942C7DB3FEBDD27840ECFF697EFDA93CC6CCF80A83F3A8487917131301BF32EF1B9E36CF; path=/

   Versus the one which is sent...

   > Cookie:ASPSESSIONIDCWCQTDDT=CINLLKKBNLNBKMPOMCPPKCFH; rcva%5F=**FCDB7353DAFB81C0DBDF61BD76CBBB0B4B6D6E39BC7381BEDB8A79416CBE4E9E**EF49F13C3FD75EBFCE526F8984772FCB4A39EE0A3563DCAFD81050CAE03092E7B0AF2A5ABB6EBE0CADF06AB9F405A1AABBC521DEF74668744D66327E2F0C6CEB17EC3757B623A057444FF457A13D97DC7438CA446840E71C358E5D1F942566602B3E31061989C8DC5A7F1F846A0680BD
5. Additionally, the form data sent also has part of that cookie with a random-generated name, and only the first 32 chars match:

   > c4134bbd3f648974b8ecdc237b5ebe2fd:**FCDB7353DAFB81C0DBDF61BD76CBBB0B**D085AD5A217BAD80C33CC6A27FDAD06DC7E81968BC5C18767860BB38E4285D9A9E02BEE0FDFF9C7B133FAC5FE6BFAC04ED88B3038686B94083AB20C44C9CB94CA067CC376892B9F9E91514A73C659E5BD05BF72B2DC8BCD5AD399D191CC58818
6. Don't do `self.cookies = r.cookies` since requests will manage the cookies in that session itself (by re-sending the received cookies). You also don't need to explicitly provide it unless you want to add a separate cookie, and should only have those items (the previously received cookies will be sent anyway).

   Note: you will need to figure out how the js is setting cookies when the form is submitted. And then re-create it in Python or...use selenium/or other headless browsers - which you've said you prefer not to do.
7. `'lang': 'en-us'` in the form data may not have the desired effect and may cause errors. To set that the way the website does, set the parameters to the page in each request: `r.get(... params={'lang': 'en-us'} ...)`. And when you do this, `'submit1'` should then be `'Login'`, for #1 above.

This doesn't provide all the info you need to login but you'll first have to make the changes above and then see where you get.

Comment: I edited my question and added the requested info. I simply cannot understand from where this `c4134bbd3f648974b8ecdc237b5ebe2fd` come from. How can I detect/catch the JS file which is responsible for this? If I do that, I can emulate the functionality of this JS in order to generate these cookies? Thanks!

Comment: Apart from the library imports like angular and jquery, there's `app.js` which doesn't seem to have much. And some obfuscated js included in the html. See if you have any success with setting everything else correctly (apart from those cookies). Otherwise, you'll need to use a browser/selenium.

Comment: Wrt _"If I do that, I can emulate the functionality of this JS in order to generate these cookies? "_ Yes, you should be able to. Can't know for sure what other pages do once you've logged in. If you're scraping data you're not supposed to (student site), then I don't think the webmaster will help. If not, you could just ask the people who wrote it.

Comment: I successfully scraped the data from there, using the `dryscrape` library. I also tried to scrape using selenium (phantomjs, chrome headless) with success. The reason that I don't want to use those methods, is that the application will be less lightweight (Duuh!). Moreover, there are 2-3 applications (android, websites), that are scraping data from there. IDK, maybe they have database access somehow, this is another issue. Also, I cannot simply ask the people who wrote it (including government). Anyway, thanks for your explanation, I think i will implement this with another method.

Comment: Great! You should post your solution as an answer.